# Mixed cart with Digital / Physical goods on in-app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, payment

I have this problem.
I start to develop a service that sell  Digital / Physical goods.
In my iOS app i have a cart that contains twice goods.
When i go to the checkout i have this problem. Some element, concerning to apple guidelines, must be payed with in in-app purchase other with "custom" methods.
There is a way to pay with a single transaction (es. use only in app-purchase, use only es. Visa) or i must do 2 payment transactions?
Another problem is if i must buy one by one digital purchase or i can buy digital item with "one tap"?
For example my cart have only 3 digitals good, it tap to proceed checkout, and the expected result is that my 3 digitals item results buyed.

Comment: It sounds like you need to process two payments.

Comment: but i have a discount price to apply that cover digital and Physical how i can do?if one transaction fail?...apple makes very complex everything.